# Demo account in itunesconnect in sms-based app

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval

I can't find any info about my problem - I've written an app, which is sms-based(it means that user has to request and receive sms from my server,  and can't continue until enter sms-code and some other things based on sms within app). So, my problem is rejecting from appstore review due to "no demo data", but how i can get it if even "demo" depends on real device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple will test your app on a real device. When they run the app, they need to be able to get past your registration process. So you need to have your system setup so when the reviewer runs your submitted app they can perform what actions your app requires. This means your server needs to be running for real.

If there is some specific information (user id, password, etc.) that the reviewer must enter into your app to use it, you must provide that information in the "Demo account" field for your app's details in iTunes Connect.

Comment: If the app login is based on SMS, how are you going to provide them with user id, password etc? The Apple tester will need to enter his/her phone number and enter the code received in the sms. There is no backdoor to the app. Is this something Apple testers can do? (enter phone # and enter code in the sms).

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution @oyalhi?

Comment: As mentioned in of the stackoverflow posts, I filled the notes section in iTunes for the tester, and it passed. The note I have written is exactly the following: 'We use login via Digits by Twitter (SMS login) and demo account will be automatically created when you enter a working phone number.' I specifically mentioned 'Digits by Twitter' to add credibility. As a  side note, Fabrics is bought by Google, but Digits is still managed by Twitter I guess.