# Is Demo account in Appstore is for public or only for Apple review?

Tags: ios, app-store, hig

I gone through SO on this topic, it seems there is no clear answer for this question.

I want to know exactly whether the demo account we give on the Appstore submission processs is exactly for Appstore review process or made available to the public use.

Because i am supplying my client's account to the Appstore review process.

Can any one help me on this topic.

Thanks

Comment: why do u prefer a demo account?

Comment: @mvp To provide access to all pages

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your app has a login functionality, you need to create and supply a test/demo account for Apple during review. This account is for App store review purpose only. You can delete this account once the app is approved.

Under [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW8)
 check **Providing App Review Information** section which says,

> Use the App Review Information section to provide contact, review notes, and demo account information so that the App Review team can review your app. If your app requires specific settings, user registrations, or account information before you submit it to the App Store, be sure to include that information in this section.

[image]

Also refer similar questions: [iPhone App Store Release Question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58923/iphone-app-store-release-question) and [Demo account in itunesconnect in sms-based app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333624/demo-account-in-itunesconnect-in-sms-based-app)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Note, there is possibly some misinformation in this answer. On iTunesConnect Apple states: _The user name and password for a full-access account for your app. This account is used during the review process and_ *must not expire*. _Include details for additional accounts in the Notes field._ This could mean that the account should not be deleted, but I don't see how Apple could verify this. Maybe they just mean it won't expire during the test phase (i.e. time based expiry).

Comment: @SandyChapman One of my apps required a login. I had created a demo account on the production server and deleted the account once the application was approved/released to the store. I did not face any issue with this process. Its important to note that when submitting an **update** to the app, you have to repeat this procedure (each time) i.e. create a demo account for Apple to test your app update. If previous demo accounts are valid, you can save the trouble of creating and setting up new ones.